# Use Google Wallet in my website for recurring payment, including user-authentication

Tags: google-api, android-pay

I have a website that provides a specific SW service.

I would like to allow users to subscribe to this SW service:

1. Sign-Up: the user provides credit card details, a username and a password.
2. Sign-In: the user enters username+password in order to get access to my SW service.

The user's credit card should be charged once per month (i.e., recurring payment).

I'm considering Google Wallet for this purpose, but there are a couple of issues that I'm concerned about:

1. Can I use the Google Wallet API in order to implement sign-up and sign-in, or should I implement user-authentication separately within my server?
2. Is the Google Wallet API available only for mobile devices? This is implied in both Google Wallet's website and in Wikipedia. My website is primarily intended for use through desktop PCs, and not through smartphones.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3):

For the sign-up / sign-in part, if you want to use Google's OAuth service you can try at the [Google+ Sign-In](https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/).

For the recurring payment part, the [Google Wallet for digital goods API](https://developers.google.com/commerce/wallet/digital/) offers a monthly subscription API and a web-based payment flow. If the user does not already have a credit card saved in their Wallet, they will be prompted only once to add a card.

Comment: Thank you Mihai. I have managed to implement the second part (subscription with  Google Wallet for digital goods API). Now I need to retrieve the username (email) of the person who has subscribed to my service, so that I can add it to a list of users who are authorized to use my service (i.e., authorized to access some protected web page that my server provides). Any idea how to retrieve the username from the Google Wallet app? Here is what I found on the web: req.getUserPrincipal().getName() or UserServiceFactory.getUserService().getCurrentUser().getEmail(). However, Both options return null.

Comment: The user email is not directly available (for privacy reasons). In your particular situation it is best to implement a login feature or use Google OAuth2 sign-in (e.g. https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2Login https://developers.google.com/+/features/sign-in)